# Replace "," in PSCustomObject's properties while retaining the object type

Tags: powershell

I have the following sample code which replaces all comma values (,) with a period (.):

```
$foo = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Num1 = "0.11"
    Num2 = "0,12"
}

Write-Host "Type before:" $foo.GetType().FullName

$foo = $foo -replace(",",".")

Write-Host "Type after:" $foo.GetType().FullName
```

It produces the following output:

> Type before: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
>
> Type after: System.String

I'd like to retain the `PSCustomObject` type and not have it converted to a string. Any ideas on how to accomplish this aside from:

```
$foo.Num2.Replace(",",".")
```

I'd prefer not to get into listing out each property with a replace statement as my real code has MANY properties in this object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell comparison operators (including the replacement operator) implicitly convert the first operand to a type that matches the second operand. In your case that is transoforming the custom object to a string representation of itself.

To replace something in the properties of your object: enumerate the properties and do the replacement operation on the actual properties, not the object as a whole.

```
$foo.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Value -is [string]) {
        $_.Value = $_.Value.Replace(',', '.')
    }
}
```